# Different values in Variables View than Console View

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest, uitest

I´m debugging an IOS application with UITest.
 I have tried to get the last index of the table but it gave me an unexpected value like 18446744073709551615.

Then I saw a problem between Variables View and Console View.
In the variables view, at the index value prints -1 but if I execute a 'po' command with the same initialization than the Index variable I got another value as you can check in the picture.

I wish that somebody could help me with this problem or tell me why is it happening.

[image: An example whta is happening]

Regards

Comment: check this question's answer i guess its very similar to yours if not the same, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203546/xcode-has-the-wrong-debug-values-while-paused-in-the-debugger hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode has the wrong debug values while paused in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203546/xcode-has-the-wrong-debug-values-while-paused-in-the-debugger)

Answer (score 2):

It is the same number. -1 = 2^^64 - 1 = 18446744073709551615. You get the last on po.